# Нужно чтобы при нажатии fps-контроллер не двигался и не мог крутить камерой

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно чтобы при нажатии (или другом действии, это неважно) fps-контроллер не мог двигаться и крутить камерой.

Ни где не могу найти как это сделать. В игре персонаж открывает телефон и он должен стоять на месте, но он может ходить и вращать камерой, что мешает игре.

Я пробовал устанавливать время на 0, но персонаж до сих пор может вращать камерой.

Подскажите как исправить.

Скрипты на с#.

Answer (score 0):

1. Кликни на обьект персонажа
2. В настройках персонажа заблокируй поворот на нужных осях

Или же сделай то же самое для камеры. А потом изменяй значения только програмно. Должно решить вопрос.